# Functionality of pthread_join() in Ubuntu C

Tags: c, ubuntu, pthreads, pthread-join

#### Working on a small C code with pthread library. My requirement for this code is to first deposit money then withdraw money.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>

int counter = 0;
void *increase();
void *decrease();

int balance = 500;

void *deposit(void*);
void *withdraw(void*);


int main() {

    pthread_t t_inc, t_dec;
    int dep_money = 300;
    int wd_money = 100;

    pthread_create(&t_inc, NULL, deposit, &dep_money);
    pthread_create(&t_dec, NULL, withdraw, &wd_money);

    // Wait until the thread is finished
    pthread_join(t_inc, NULL);
    pthread_join(t_dec, NULL);
    }
    return 0;
}

// Functions for thread
void *deposit(void *args) {
    int *money = (int *)args;
    balance += *money;
    printf("Deposit: New balance: %d\n", balance);
    return NULL;
}

void *withdraw(void *args) {
    int *money = (int *)args;

    if (balance < *money) {
        printf("Not enough balance\n");
    } else {
        balance -= *money;
        printf("Withdraw: New balance: %d\n", balance);
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

#### I have used this code on 2 different operating systems, Ubuntu & macOS. I have got for some reason 2 different results.

For macOS:

> Deposit: New balance: 800

> Withdraw: New balance: 700

For Ubuntu:

> Withdraw: New balance: 400

> Deposit: New balance: 700

#### But when I change the order of pthread_join() in Ubuntu it worked as the order I wanted it.

```
pthread_create(&t_inc, NULL, deposit, &dep_money);
pthread_join(t_inc, NULL);

pthread_create(&t_dec, NULL, withdraw, &w_money);
pthread_join(t_dec, NULL);
```

> In conclusion, my question is why in the first code run in Ubuntu it didn't run as the first order of the pthread_join(t_inc, NULL); then the second pthread_join(t_dec, NULL); instead it runs the opposite? And I had to call pthread_join() after pthread_create() immediately for it to work in order which I don't think it's efficient since I didn't create the second thread yet.

Comment: It seems to me this is just a race condition, and has nothing to do with what OS you use.

Comment: How can it ever be efficient to create two threads just to do two jobs that cannot overlap? Won't it always be more efficient to use one thread instead of three?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's just a race condition. Calling `pthread_create` of one thread *before* that of the other ***does not guarantee*** that the second thread shall be scheduled by the OS after the first. So calling

```
pthread_create(&t_inc, NULL, deposit, &dep_money);
pthread_create(&t_dec, NULL, withdraw, &wd_money);
```

doesn't mean that you'll invoke the thread running `deposit()` before the one running `withdraw()`. It's totally up to the OS on when they are actually scheduled and as a programmer, one should not make any assumptions about it. Hence the discrepancies in the result because any one of the thread might run before.

So, to answer your question

> my question is why in the first code run in Ubuntu it didn't run as
> the first order of the pthread_join(t_inc, NULL); then the second
> pthread_join(t_dec, NULL); instead it runs the opposite?

Don't have any expectations about the order in which threads are actually run.

Calling

```
pthread_create(&t_inc, NULL, deposit, &dep_money);
pthread_join(t_inc, NULL);

pthread_create(&t_dec, NULL, withdraw, &w_money);
pthread_join(t_dec, NULL);
```

will always work since you have essentially serialized the thread creation and the thread calling `deposit()` shall always complete before the one running `withdraw()` is spawned and thus it works on all OSs.

EDIT:

For completeness, as you mentioned, creating threads and immediately calling `join()` isn't really of much use since it is as good as just calling the functions `deposit()` and `withdraw()` in order, given that here `deposit()` and `withdraw()` don't really do much significant work that might stall the main thread, blocking it to proceed to do other tasks. Also, you would usually need to take care of shared variables. e.g. If you just had a single variable `amount` and then each thread updated the same value, one adding balance and another deducting it, then you could be possibly needing constructs like [`mutex`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/pthread_mutex_lock.html)/[`condition_variable`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/pthread_cond_wait.html) to achieve your desired results, free of race conditions.

Comment: @JohnBollinger certainly. In this case, direct calling the functions might just be adequate. Let me update this in the answer too for completeness.